# Magento how to store user data

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around Magento.

I need to store a number of settings files for each user of a web app.
The user can add and delete any number of settings files.
 
I just need to store the following for each file added.

{
 
     name: name of the settings
     filepath: path to the settings file
     date: date created
}

What is the easiest way to add these for each customer. As a product?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create your own module to allow for uploading of these settings, and to read them out and use them.  Easiest would probably be to create your own table for the module with name, filepath, date but also the internal Magento customer ID.  If you only needed one of these it would be sufficient to add it as customer attributes.

There's lots of guides and tutorials on how to set up your own table with a custom module, here's one:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try walking through the guide you linked to. This Magento system is killing me.